# Adding files to gitignore in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

In Visual Studio Code, with git extensions installed, how do you add files or complete folders to the .gitignore file so the files do not show up in untracked changes. Specifically, using Python projects, how do you add the **pycache** folder and its contents to the .gitignore. I have tried right-clicking in the folder in explorer panel but the pop-menu has no git ignore menu option. Thanks in advance.

I know how to do it from the command line. Yes, just edit the .gitignore file. I was just asking how it can be done from within VS Code IDE using the git extension for VS Code.

Comment: VSC is NOT an IDE. `.gitignore` is a text file and can be edited simply, adding a few directories or file extensions is a piece of cake. If you really want see if you can add menu entries to these context menus and create an extension to modify .gitignore

Comment: @rioV8 Visual Studio Code is essentially a code editor, which is highly extensible. So, with the right set of plug-ins and the right set of instructions, you can configure it to become an IDE with a good toolchain. The line between IDE and non-IDE has blurred over the years, as code editors have become smarter and more extensible.

Comment: there is a `gitignore` extension that allows to also add folders to git ignore (via righ-click in the file explorer)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So after further investigation, it is possible to add files from the pycache folder to the .gitignore file from within VS Code by using the list of untracked changed files in the 'source control' panel. You right-click a file and select add to .gitignore from the pop-up menu. You can't add folders but just the individual files.

Answer (score 7):

[This extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=michelemelluso.gitignore) lets you add folders to .gitignore.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select "**Source Control**" from left menu
2. Select one for the file from the folder to ignore, right click and add to .gitignore file
3. Previous operation will create a .gitignore file on app home path
4. open .gitignore file in editor and change the added file to regex to exclude entire directory/folder

> abc/cde/file1.py  ==> abc/**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extension, nor do you need to use the terminal. Just open the `.gitignore` file in an editor tab and then edit it in the editor tab. It might be helpful for you to copy the path by right clicking the thing in the Explorer View and selecting "Copy Relative Path", or right clicking the tab handle of the editor tab if the file is open. You can then paste it into the gitignore with a leading forward slash. Note that you can also add the file in the currently focused editor tab to the top-level gitignore file by using `Git: Add to .gitignore` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).

I know this sounds like a joke suggestion, but I'm serious. I like writing my config files by hand because I actually care about reading them later, and how to make them readable to myself later. I care about what order the lines of my gitignores are in, which lines are grouped together, *which gitignore file I put something in* when I have multiple of them, whether I want to generalize a pattern using stars, etc. When I use some IDE feature to do this, the IDE usually doesn't know about the nuances of how I want to organize things and just plops it in the simplest place and in the simplest manner that works (Ex. appending to the end of the file). That's just a no-go for me.

Answer (score 0):

An extension (sorry) if I may...Somehow, there were **pycache** directories in the repository already.  Adding "**/**pycache**" to the .gitignore did nothing until I first removed those.

Using "git rm -r -f **pycache**" from the VSC terminal worked.  For some reason, I had to drill down to each folder containing a pycache subdirectory, the **/ syntax didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From the source control/pending changes section you can right click on the items under changes and add to .gitignore

Answer (score -2):

You can use the terminal in VS Code to do this:

1. Create a .gitignore file
2. echo file_name > .gitignore (This ensures that the file is written into the .gitignore file)

Comment: 1) ah yes. nuke the whole thing while you're at it 2) If you're going to take this approach, why not just edit the file in an editor tab?

Comment: In my opinion you should use `echo file_name >> .gitignore`. That appends to a new line of the .gitignore file instead nuking the entire one.